# Finding the acceleration of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I uploaded a picture with the problem from the textbook and its solution

First of all, i understood the solution from the solution manual, but in my solution the only thing that is different is that i choose the positive x direction to be upwards the ramp , which is the oposite direction choosen in the solution manual With said, i got the following equation for the NET force on each box T-m1•g=m1•a T-m2•g•sin55=m2•a Doing the álgebra, i get a=-7.4, which is in the same direction as the a from the solution, but with a different magnitude, so my question is, are my 2 equations above wrong? and shouldn't every choice of coordinate system give us a correct anwser?
problem
[image: problem]

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sign on one of the $a$'s is wrong. In $T-m_1g=m_1 a$ you assume $a$ positive upwards. In $T-m_2g\sin(55)=m_2a$ you assume $a$ positive upwards along the incline as well. Both can't be possible at the same time.

If you choose a positive axis up along the ramp for the latter equation and added up the forces with signs based on that, then the acceleration must be negative. If you chose it down along the ramp, the acceleration would be positive, but the forces would also change signs.

So no, the chosen coordinate system doesn't matter, but the signs must be set consistently both throughout all variables *within* one equation/coordinate system and also across different coordinate systems. Otherwise you have set up an impossible/unphysical situation which will only give you correspondingly impossible/unphysical answers.

Comment: One way to help avoid this common pitfall is to write Newton's second law completely locally for each object, and then write an equation coupling the two.  In this case, there would be an equation for object 1 containing acceleration $a_1$, and likewise for 2, and equation containing $a_2$, and finally, after some consideration, $a_1=-a_2$.   Three equations in three unknowns.   More cumbersome, but more systematic (less thinking, always a good thing in my case).